# Proving partial derivative identity

Tags: partial-derivative, proof-explanation

stuck on the following question:

Let **H(x,y)** be a differentiable function satisfying

$$h(tx,ty)=t^kH(x,y) $$ for all real *x,y,t,* where *k* is a positive integer. Prove the identity
$$xH_x(x,y) + yH_y(x,y)=kH(x,y)$$
for all real *x,y*.

This is what I have attempted:

Let *a=tx* and *b=ty*
 so we have $$H(a,b)=t^kH(x,y)$$

Differentiated the first equation with respect to t to get

$$\frac{dH}{da} .\frac{da}{dt}+\frac{dH}{db} .\frac{db}{dt}=kt^{k-1}h(x,y)$$
$$\frac{da}{dt}=x$$ $$\frac{db}{dt}=y$$

So, $$\frac{dH}{da}x+\frac{dH}{db}y=kt^{k-1}H(x,y)$$

So if we divide the $t^{k-1}$, $$\frac{\frac{dH}{da}x+\frac{dH}{db}y}{t^{k-1}}=kH(x,y)$$

$$H_x(x,y)= \frac{dH}{dx}=\frac{dH}{da}.\frac{da}{dx}=\frac{dH}{da}.t$$
$$H_y(x,y)= \frac{dH}{dx}=\frac{dH}{db}.\frac{db}{dx}=\frac{dH}{db}.t$$

Therefore,  $$\frac{xH_x(x,y)+yH_y(x,y)}{t^{k-2}}=kH(x,y)$$

Which means $t^{k-2}$ must equal 1, which is not true.

Any help on where I've gone wrong would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. The identity 
$$\frac{xH_x(x,y)+yH_y(x,y)}{t^{k-2}}=kH(x,y)$$

is true for all $t\neq0$, *in particular* it is true for $t=1$ which gives what you want.

Comment: So I would conclude this question by stating that for t=1, the identity is true? Wouldn't that be specifying t too much when t is supposed to be for all real numbers?

Comment: @JasonHuang As I wrote, if it is true for many values, it is true for one of it :) and you get the announced identity...

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't think I could do that

Comment: You are welcome.